# ajax post error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101 on android device

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax

I have the following ajax post:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://sampleurl",
    data: {
        'email':$('#email').val(),
        'password':$('#password').val(),
    },
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    crossDomain: "true",
    beforeSend: function() { },
    complete: function() { },
    success: function(resp) {
        alert(resp);
        var result = $.parseJSON(resp);

        if (result.result == "Success") {   
            alert(emailID,password);
        }
        else {
            alert(result.msg);
        }
    },
    error: function(request, status, error) {
        //$("#LoadingImage").hide();
        alert("Result = " + error);
    }
});
return false;
});
```

It is returning with this error: `NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101` on android tablet.

I have read a bunch of SO posts on this error, most suggest that I set `async` to `true`. This DOES remove the error message- but it is still an error, and I never get valid data. It just seems to remove the error message which is not helpful.

Please help me.

Comment: You should definitely remove the `async: false`. What is the error you get then? Also, check the `status` in the `error` handler.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan If you see my last comment then just ignore me.  Not had enough coffee yet :)

Comment: @Archer you're lucky, I missed it :D

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i tried but now alert showing empty window

Comment: android 4.0 is working but problem with android 4.1.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i got solution.. Android 4.1 and 4.2 introduce this new method: getAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs

Since it's not working on API below 16 the solution needs some few more lines, to assure that this inexistent method do not cause errors in previous API.

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
    fixNewAndroid(webView);
}

@TargetApi(16)
protected void fixNewAndroid(WebView webView) {
try {
    webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
} catch(NullPointerException e) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try use location in your domain , like `./directory/yourfile.php`
I have this problem in IE7

Comment: browser i have no problem.. i have with android 4.1.x device